# $\text{cond}_2^2(M)= \text{cond}_2(M^T M)$ for non square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, condition-number

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix with full colum rank. Proof

$$
\text{cond}_2^2(M)= \text{cond}_2(M^T M).
$$

---

What I got so far:

Denote the pseudo-inverse (Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse) of $M$ with $M^+$.

$$\text{cond}_2^2(M) = ||M^{+}||_2^2 \cdot||M||_2^2  = \lambda_{\text{max}} ((M^+)^T M^+) \cdot \lambda_{\text{max}}(M^T M)$$

where $\lambda_{\text{max}}(\cdot)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of the matrix. We also have

$$\text{cond}_2(M^T M) = ||(M^T M)^{-1}||_2 \cdot ||M^T M||_2 \\= \left( \lambda_{\text{max}}(((M^T M)^{-1})^T(M^T M)^{-1}) \cdot \lambda_{\text{max}}((M^T M)^T (M^T M)) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\ 
= \lambda_{\text{max}}((M^T M)^{-1}) \cdot \lambda_{\text{max}}(M^T M)$$

So, if we compare the two equations, we see the right hand side is the same, hence we are left to show the following identity.

$$
||M^+||_2^2 = ||(M^TM)^{-1}||_2
$$

or

$$\lambda_{\text{max}} ((M^+)^T M^+) = 
\lambda_{\text{max}}((M^T M)^{-1})
$$

But I have no idea how to show this identity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ has full column rank, then $M^+=(M^TM)^{-1}M^T$. So
$$
\begin{split}
\|M^+\|_2^2&=\lambda_\max((M^+)^TM^+)
\\&=\lambda_\max(M^+(M^+)^T)
\\&=\lambda_\max((M^TM)^{-1}M^TM(M^TM)^{-1})
\\&=\lambda_\max((M^TM)^{-1}).
\end{split}
$$